# Python packages are imported on terminal but not on IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, anaconda

So I am new in Python. I downloaded Anaconda (and Homebrew) and using Terminal on my Mac I confirmed that, say, Numpy is installed:

```
pip install numpy
```

to get as a result

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Then opening Python within Terminal I can indeed import the package. The story is not the same once I open IDLE. So when I open it and try to import, say, Numpy I get the following message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I guess there is something I do not know, I assume it is a common rookie problem. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you do `import sys`, then `print (sys.version)` from your Python terminal and from IDLE? Possibly you are using a different Python version with IDLE than the one you use from the command line.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein you are right. In Terminal I have version 2.7.10  while in IDLE I have 3.6.2. So how do I resolve this? I do not like working on Terminal and Jupyter is not that handy for learning Python at the moment (for me). I would like to use IDLE

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

See when you are working with Anaconda it creates its own virtual environment.
Now, If you are new in python on MAC then you might not familiar with Virtual Environment.

I suggest you to download **python** from the official website [www.python.org](http://www.python.org)
or [Click here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.2/python-3.6.2-macosx10.6.pkg) to directly download Python 3.6.2 on your MAC.

Then, Download **Pycharm**(The Best IDE for Python)
Download the community version for beginner and it is also free.

Pycharm Community Version -> [Click Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=mac)

And do whatever you want and also must read about **Virtualenv**

According to me, **Pycharm is better then Anaconda's Jupyter Notebook**

Wish you good luck and show your creativity in python ! !

Comment: Pycharm is like Anaconda? I have installed python from the official website. Then I tried to install packages but I could not (including pip). So I found the solution of anaconda but it seems to run different version of Python.

Comment: Also, what is Virtualenv? Do I download it from somewhere?

Comment: Well I do prefer PyCharm too. Just a point to raise that actually PyCharm & Anaconda are not comparable (Anaconda is python distribution whereas PyCharm is just a plain simple IDE), I think you were try to compare Anaconda's Jupyter Notebook & Pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

Since your IDLE is using Python 3 you should use

```
pip3 install numpy
```

to get it installed for the correct Python. If you want to use your default installed Python (2.x) instead, IDLE is located at /usr/bin/. From your terminal you can open it with

```
/usr/bin/idle
```

this should have the numpy you installed with `pip install numpy`

Comment: Thanks. Well, I have managed to install numpy for Python 3 and use it with Jupyter. To do so I had to create a virtualenv. Not sure how to do the same but instead of Jupyter use IDLE (the one that comes with the Python installation package)

Answer (score 1):

Erm... well it appears as though - since you have 2 versions on your computer - that it might be because it imported it into the other file path directory. Now, I've never worked with Mac, but I think if you just specify which pip you want to download from, it might work.
For example, on Windows:

> C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install numpy

or if you were doing it for 3.6, you would follow the path to the folder, find pip and install. So, I suggest to install the normal IDLE before any other platform built upon it just because it is easier to import modules and is not as bad to break like yours has.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two issues -

1. You are using python 2 as a kernel for IDLE, since `numpy` is installed for python3.6. This will raise an error.
2. The issue is with anaconda's configuration with IDLE. Anaconda installs numpy in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages. If IDLE uses systems default python instead of anaconda's. You will not be able to import numpy.

You can try running this snippet -
`import sys 
print('\n'.join(sys.path))`
to track the location of python exactly.

One of the workaround that I can think of is -
create a virtual environment using anaconda. Something like
`conda create -n py352 python=3.5.2 anaconda`
and then fire IDLE from your terminal. Though I am not entirely sure, if this works for mac. If it doesn't, let me know the output of -
`import sys 
print('\n'.join(sys.path))`